# Purpose of black overlay in flex circuit design

Tags: fpc

Does anyone know the purpose of the black overlay I see applied to flexible circuits inside phones?  This is inside the S7, I see the same thing in the iphone.  It's clearly been applied on top of the coverlay.  So what purpose does it serve.  Could be EMI maybe?  Maybe it's just for style...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is a conductive EMI shield

Comment: May actually be a ferrite type material. It is for EMI, but it is not necessarily a conductive shield.

Answer (score -1):

We used it to hide cosmetic defects. Compare opaque black CL against clear brown CL.

What the customer can't see they can't reject.